# Insert proper phone format

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, t-sql

I have a textbox which stores phone number.

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="phone" MaxLength="10" Columns="10" Width="90px" />
                        <asp:MaskedEditExtender ID="phone_MaskedEditExtender" runat="server" CultureAMPMPlaceholder=""
                            CultureCurrencySymbolPlaceholder="" CultureDateFormat="" CultureDatePlaceholder=""
                            CultureDecimalPlaceholder="" CultureThousandsPlaceholder="" CultureTimePlaceholder=""
                            Enabled="True" TargetControlID="phone" Mask="(999)-999-9999" ClearMaskOnLostFocus="False">
                        </asp:MaskedEditExtender>
```

The question is when I insert phone number 9999999999, the number in the database becomes
(999)-9999.
What I want is 9999999999.
The other code is:

```
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="InsertExtraInfo" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MembershipDB %>"
                    InsertCommand="CreateAdditionalAccountInfo" InsertCommandType="StoredProcedure">
                    <InsertParameters>
                        <asp:ControlParameter Name="FirstName" Type="String" ControlID="FirstName" PropertyName="Text" />
                        <asp:ControlParameter Name="LastName" Type="String" ControlID="LastName" PropertyName="Text" />
                        <asp:ControlParameter Name="Degree" Type="String" ControlID="Degree" PropertyName="Text" />
                        <asp:ControlParameter Name="Organization" Type="String" ControlID="Organization"
                            PropertyName="Text" />
                        <asp:ControlParameter Name="Phone" Type="String" ControlID="Phone" PropertyName="Text" />
                        <asp:ControlParameter Name="Ext" Type="String" ControlID="Ext" PropertyName="Text" />
                        <asp:ControlParameter Name="last4SSN" Type="String" ControlID="TextSSN" PropertyName="Text" />
                    </InsertParameters>
                </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

The stored Procedure query is

```
INSERT INTO [User_ExtraInfo] ([UserId], [FirstName], [LastName], [Degree], [Organization], [Phone], [Ext], [last4SSN],[Trained]) VALUES (@UserId, @FirstName, @LastName, @Degree, @Organization, @Phone, @Ext
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the proc to this:

```
INSERT INTO [User_ExtraInfo] ([UserId], [FirstName], [LastName], [Degree], [Organization], [Phone], [Ext], [last4SSN],[Trained]) VALUES (@UserId
, @FirstName
, @LastName
, @Degree
, @Organization
, REPLACE(REPLACE( REPLACE(@Phone,'(',''),')','') ,'-','')  , @Ext )
```

The reason I suggest this approach is because you are using a SQLDatasource object and I don't think it's possible to instruct the insert parameter -at least not declaratively from the markup- to ignore the mask. Your best bet is probably just to modify the proc.

**UPDATE - programmatic approach:**

1. Add a handler for OnInserting to the SqlDataSource:

   ```
   <asp:SqlDataSource ID="InsertExtraInfo" runat="server" OnInserting="On_Inserting"
   ```
2. Handle the event on code and do the replacement there:

   ```
   protected void On_Inserting(Object sender, SqlDataSourceCommandEventArgs e) {
    e.Command.Parameters["@Phone"].Value=phone.Text.Replace("..."); // etc
   }
   ```

Note: not tested but it's the idea.

Comment: If you could do it without changing proc is better because I don't have permission to change it.

Comment: @Love read my update. That's should be close to what you need.

Comment: e.Command.Parameters["@Phone"] or e.Command.Parameters["Phone"]? I got an exception.

Comment: @Love I am not sure but it's one of those two. Try it, it's easier for you to try than for my to take a guess.

Comment: An SqlParameter with ParameterName 'Phone' is not contained by this SqlParameterCollection.